# UIAlert with AddSubview replacement for iOS 7

Tags: objective-c

Current code works perfectly before iOS 7, on iOS 7 there is no field to input the name of the user, from scanning these forums I noticed t changed on iOS7 something to do with the addsubview function, here is the current code;

Could anyone assist in converting this to work with iOS7 (ideally not breaking the iOS 6 link as would prefer to keep the app compatible with both OS versions)

```
- (void) createScoreInput {

    changePlayerAlert = [UIAlertView new];
    changePlayerAlert.title = @"Enter your name";
    changePlayerAlert.message = @"\n\n";
    changePlayerAlert.delegate = self;
    [changePlayerAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Save"];
    [changePlayerAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    CGRect frame = changePlayerAlert.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= 100.0f;
    changePlayerAlert.frame = frame;

    changePlayerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 245, 27)];

    changePlayerTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [changePlayerAlert addSubview:changePlayerTextField];
    changePlayerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
    changePlayerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    changePlayerTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    changePlayerTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    changePlayerTextField.delegate = self;


}
```

Comment: As of iOS 7 Apple states in there documentation that you can not change the [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html): `The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`

Comment: @rckoenes I also believe this was also the case in iOS 6 and iOS 5 but Apple are now actually being more strict about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API has solution for your problem use this  and have fun

https://github.com/Darktt/DTAlertView

https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView

[image]

https://github.com/lmcd/LMAlertView

[image]

OR

Follow [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation--mobile-8388) tutorial and you can take input directly from `UIAlertView`